# GEKKO Singular Matrix Problem with BPOPT and Solver Selection

Tags: gekko

1. I used MODES = 7 to sequentially solve a simulation problem with BPOPT solver. The solver can solve the first few problems but report the following error:

```
 *** WARNING MESSAGE FROM SUBROUTINE MA27BD  *** INFO(1) = 3

     MATRIX IS SINGULAR. RANK=  581

 Problem with linear solver, INFO:            3
```

2. With solver=0, I can see the GEKKO has 6 different solvers. I wonder how can I specify a solver (like MINOS).

Answer (score 0):

You can change solvers with `m.options.SOLVER=1` for APOPT or `m.options.SOLVER=3` for IPOPT. The other solvers aren't available for public use because they require a license.

The error message that you are receiving is because the solver could not find a search direction. I recommend including variable bounds such as lower bound of zero for some variables to prevent singular solutions.

If you'd like more specific help, please post minimal, verifiable code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The whole model is bit complicated. Another things is, I'm wondering can with IMODE=7, how do I let the solver search the solution with my initial value. Currently, I'm a solving the problem consecutively. Each problem represent 30s' simulation. I would like to use the previous problem's solution to help to solve the next 30s simulation.

Comment: Gekko warm starts from the prior solution automatically. For dynamic problems, an option is `m.options.TIME_SHIFT` where you can control how many time steps in the future that Gekko uses to create a new initial condition and time shift all of the other node points for a warm start. This is used for `m.options.IMODE=4`. A time shift of 1 is automatic and should be used for `m.options.IMODE=7`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way that I can add a exit condition with IMODE=7? Once some variables surpass some setpoints, the problem will stop solving and return the result.

Comment: You would need to put the solve in a loop and check the conditions after each solution. There isn't a way to terminate early unless you introduce a constraint such as `m.Equation(x<10)` and then see how many steps it takes until the problem become infeasible.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to find out the steps? With below example,

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
x = m.Var(1, ub=10)
m.Equation(x.dt() == 2)
m.options.IMODE = 7
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve(disp=False)

Before hitting the upper bound of x, the problem can solve few steps. But gekko didn't return the result. Is there any way I can recover the solution for the first few steps?

Comment: There isn't currently a way to do that. I recommend that you shorten the horizon to `m.time = np.linspace(0,3,4)` and retrieve the solution. If you just need simulation then ODEINT may be a better option for this problem where you need to terminate early: https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SolveDifferentialEquations